# Why HTTP_REFERER is single r, not HTTP_REFERRER?

Tags: http, networking, network-protocols

Sometimes my facebook friend confuses HTTP_REFERER and HTTP_REFERRER, because in the dictionary there is referrer only.
Why does that misspelled standard protocol define, and why they don't try to correct the bug?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer

> **Origin of the term referer**
>
> The misspelling referer originated in the original proposal by
>   computer scientist Phillip Hallam-Baker to incorporate the field into
>   the HTTP specification.[1] The misspelling was set in stone by the
>   time of its incorporation into the standards document Request for
>   Comments (RFC) 1945; document co-author Roy Fielding has remarked that
>   neither "referrer" nor the misspelling "referer" were recognized by
>   the standard Unix spell checker of the period.[2] "Referer" has since
>   become a widely used spelling in the industry when discussing HTTP
>   referrers; usage of the misspelling is not universal, though, as the
>   correct spelling of "referrer" is used in some web specifications such
>   as the Document Object Model.

Answer (score 4):

See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer)

> The misspelling referer originated in the original proposal by
>   computer scientist Phillip Hallam-Baker to incorporate the field into
>   the HTTP specification.[1] The misspelling was set in stone by the
>   time of its incorporation into the standards document Request for
>   Comments (RFC) 1945; document co-author Roy Fielding has remarked that
>   neither "referrer" nor the misspelling "referer" were recognized by
>   the standard Unix spell checker of the period.[2] "Referer" has since
>   become a widely used spelling in the industry when discussing HTTP
>   referrers; usage of the misspelling is not universal, though, as the
>   correct spelling of "referrer" is used in some web specifications such
>   as the Document Object Model.

Answer (score 1):

You may have noticed the word “referrer” is misspelled as “referer”. Unfortunately it made into the official HTTP specifications like that and got stuck.